# Why does return View (user) clear the query string in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, view, asp.net-mvc-5

I use ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have an `AccountController` and a `ChangePassword(string guid)` action method with a `HttpGet` attribute.

This action gets a guid and shows change password view, for a specific user.

URL address in browser is for example:

```
https://localhost:3434/ChangePassword?guid=21725E33A1FD4FCE909770B8926FB294
```

When user enters a valid value, everything is OK.

But if the user enters an invalid value, I return a view (user) to show the view with entered value.

URL is changed to

```
https://localhost:3434/ChangePassword
```

and we lose the guid in the query string.

Is there any way to save the guid in the query string after post?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(string guid)
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(clsUser user)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View(user);
   }
   else
   {
      do something ....
   }
}
```

Comment: QueryString parameters are used only in case of GET. Your invalid model is a response for a POST.

Comment: what is clsUser ?  What is in ChangePassword view?